# PHP script to move a directory from one Linux server to another?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an image folder on my test.com/images/item1 with 2-3 sub folder in it. A user on test.com check the images and then move this whole image folder on test2.com/images/.

Now i did it with command prompt. But i need a php script which move or copy this image folder  on one server to another using php script.

Comment: the main problem is not whether PHP can do it, but whether it has permissions to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//you can use ssh connect like this

```
<?php
       $connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
       ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

       ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
?>
```

Comment: check this link for more detail information http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php#71197

Comment: thanks,Yes reached near to my solution now more i need to do by myself

Answer (score 2):

the tool rsync will help you, a brief usage:
system('rsync -Rtp filename > target_server::module')

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your Question is "Yes", you can Exec or SSH or FTP, or SFTP, you can do all these depending on your situation and requirement. Ask complete question to what you want us to help with :).

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this but the easiest seems to be to send your cmd with php's exec or passthru function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

> Warning
>
> When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use
>   escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() to ensure that users cannot trick
>   the system into executing arbitrary commands.

Comment: Actually i have to pass some variable every time, like which user folder should move. Every time source path will be different. On the basis of selection of checkbox.

Comment: no problem, put the var into the cmd. But be carefull (see the warning in passthru docs)